# Can Vagrant be usable without Mac Admin privileges?

Tags: macos, vagrant, admin

I have a classroom that I'd love to have students use the more industry-standard Vagrant and VirtualBox to run development web servers instead of XAMPP or MAMP or whatever.

Let's assume that Vagrant and VirtualBox are already installed by an administrator. How can a mac user without general admin/sudo privileges use Vagrant to start a scotch/box or a laravel/homestead image? Is it even possible?

Should I even consider doing this? Is this critically dangerous to the host computer or network if students download a box to use maliciously?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible when you have permission to execute Vagrant.
The easiest way to do it would be to issue:

```
vagrant init scotch/box
```

and then

```
vagrant up
```

You can replace scotch/box with the laravel/homestead box to run this box as well.

I see that on scotch.io website they have tutorials for both boxes and a Github repo which you can clone for Vagrantfile.
The best way for you would be to follow those tutorials [scotch/box](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/introducing-scotch-box-a-vagrant-lamp-stack-that-just-works) and [laravel/homestead](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead)

Good luck and have fun!